# Was there a battle were Russians forces rallied around a religious icon to achieve victory?

Tags: russia, identification

I remember on my last visit to Moscow, there was an incredible art piece where a group of priests carrying orthodox icons are surrounded by soldiers with spears and swords.

I remember the legend behind the piece was something along the lines of:

> After an initial defeat, the priests come out of the cathedral with the icons. The Russian forces regroup around them and ended up winning the battle".

I cant remember the name of the city, the year or against who they were fighting, but I would like to see that picture again.

Does anyone remember a battle where this has happened?

Comment: Wallace will be after u in no time

Comment: Nope - This is the exception to the rule; OP has provided all the information that is available and is concealing nothing.  We're all starting from the same place on this one.

Comment: There are many such paintings. If you want to find out the one that you saw, please include more detail, at least about the epoch of the battle. Did you see firearms in the picture? Or knights in armor with spears and bows? Were the soldiers dressed in any kind of uniform? Or you are talking about a medieval battle?

Comment: The priest were coming from the left, they were more than one and the in the front was holding an icon over his head with both arms.

the priest were all dressed in light/ white colors, surrounded by soldiers with spears and swords.

the enemy is on the right of the painting and you can see them recoiling

Im going crazy googling images of russian art, but can't seem to find it.

Maybe i should search in cyrilic?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not absolutely sure, but one possibility could be the 1612 Battle of Moscow, where the icon of Our Lady of Kazan, one of the most revered by the Russian Orthodox Church as it appears, was carried into battle by Prince Pozharski against the Poles.
According to several sources, like [OrhodoxWiki](http://orthodoxwiki.org/Our_Lady_of_Kazan),

> Hermogen [...] called for a three-day fast and ordered the icon of Our
>   Lady of Kazan to be brought to Princes Minin and Pozharsky, who were
>   leading the resistance to the occupation. This icon [...] was carried
>   before their regiments as they fought to regain the capital from the
>   Poles. When the Polish army was finally driven from Moscow on October
>   22, 1612, the victory was attributed to the intercession of the Mother
>   of God, and the Kazan icon became a focal point for Russian national
>   sentiments.

Comment: After googling some, it COULD be the answer...

But I can't find the painting and it was a big one in an important museum.

Should I post on art exchange or we should keep investigating here? :D

Comment: @user12137 that could help, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Found it in 3 minutes looking for it in Cyrillic!!!

[Moscow battle 1612](http://mtdata.ru/u26/photo4986/20169322775-0/original.jpg) - битва Mockba 1612 in Google